# Pdf no muestra imagen en aplicacion win genexus (java)

Tags: java, pdf, genexus

Tengo una aplicación Win desarrollada en **Genexus X Ev2 U2** generando en java y tengo un reporte en **PDF** en el cual tengo que incluir una imagen en un `PrintBlock` dentro del objeto proc, el problema es que no me está mostrando la imagen.

En el Runtime log me aparece el siguiente error:

> "C:\ProgramData\Genexus Web Start\NOMBRE_APLICACION\Resources\logo.jpg
>   (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)"

Osea que la aplicación está yendo a buscar la imagen a esa ruta especifica y no dentro del .jar generado. La imagen se está mostrando correctamente tanto si la agrego en un `form` como si la intento visualizar con el visor de reportes de **Genexus** (quitando la regla `output_file(...)`) por lo que intuyo que es un problema especifico con los PDF.

Datos adicionales:

- En las reglas puse "`Output_file('Reporte',"PDF");`".
- La imágen se trata de un objeto de genexus (no un blob traido de BD; con un blob si funciona).
- Propiedad Report output esta en "Only To Screen".
- Tengo incluida en el classpath el iText.jar.
- La propiedad Base Image Path esta vacía porque leí en la documentación de GX que en X Ev2 ya no es necesaria ya que las imágenes son tratados como objetos de la KB. Igualmente probe poner una ubicación por las dudas y el problema persiste.

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Cómo has configurado la ubicación de la imagen en tu proyecto? Puede que allí esté el problema.

Comment: Importé la imagen como `is external: False` para que la incluya en mi proyecto como todas las demas imagenes de la KB. Igualmente, el problema con esta imagen se da solamente en los PDF; en los demás lugares las muestra correctamente. Lo que no entiendo es porque en el pdf la va a buscar a esa ubicación especifica y no a la ubicacion absoluta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se trata de un problema conocido el cual se soluciona incorporando el archivo images.txt al jar armado por el deployment según lo expresado por [Ursula Bartram](https://uy.linkedin.com/in/ubartram) en este [blog](http://genexusnet.blogspot.com.uy/2010/09/re-java-l-imagenes-en-aplicaciones-java.html).-

Como lo explica allí Ursula, la solución pasa por abrir el .jar con winrar y agregar ese archivo el cual se puede localizar en el directorio del modelo.

Cabe destacar que según lo investigado, un problema similar se daba también generando en ambiente Win -.Net generando c# con la Gx. Ev1. Como se expresa en este [foro](http://www.gxopen.com/forumsr/servlet/viewthread?artech,1,159657) un workarround similar (llevar el archivo images.txt) también habría resuelto el problema.